# Calculate the average of this two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, average

What I'm now looking for is a way to print the average of second row of this code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MojaLoi{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [][] a = new int[6][6];

    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){
            a[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Any reply greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate average of just the second row use:

```
float sum = 0;
for(int j=0; j<a[0].length; j++){
    sum += a[1][j];   // i = 1 for second row
}
float average = sum / a[0].length;
System.out.println(average);
```

Comment: for example if this is my array
{{1 2 3 4 5 6},
{7 8 9 10 11 12},
{13 14 15 16 17 18}, 
{19 20 21 22 23 24},
{25 26 27 28 29 30}, 
{31 32 33 34 35 36}
Then I want to print the average of the second row which is {7,8,9,10,11,12}

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for.